# How to import zip file from batch importation in Windows?

Tags: dspace

i'm trying to import a zip file in windows by batch import dspace in prompt but the windows is not recognizing the DIR from file:

Apparently it is outputting twice the file path: How i can solve this?

C:\dspace5\bin>dspace import -a -e admin -c capes/218424 -s C:\Users\admins\Desktop\projects\community\migration\bitstreams   -z SimpleArchiveFormat.zip  -m mapfilesCOM

```
Using DSpace installation in: C:\dspace5
Destination collections:
Owning  Collection: materials
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\admins\Desktop\projects\community\migration\bitstreams\C:\Users\admins\Desktop\projects\community\migration\bitstreams\SimpleArchiveFormat.zip (The syntax of the file name, directory name, or volume label is incorrect)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport.unzip(ItemImport.java:2021)
        at org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport.unzip(ItemImport.java:1987)
        at org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport.unzip(ItemImport.java:2098)
        at org.dspace.app.itemimport.ItemImport.main(ItemImport.java:490)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.runOneCommand(ScriptLauncher.java:226)
        at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:78)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\admins\Desktop\projects\community\migration\bitstreams\C:\Users\admins\Desktop\projects\community\migration\bitstreams\SimpleArchiveFormat.zip (The syntax of the file name, directory name, or volume label is incorrect)

Deleting temporary zip directory: /dspace5/imports
Started: 1512488260816
Ended: 1512488268886

Elapsed time: 8 secs (8070 msecs)
```

Comment: Some java utilities expect paths to be formatted as unix paths.  Try changing the "\" to "/".  I do not have a DSpace instance running on Windows, so I am unable to verify this on my end.

Comment: I tried this, it returned the same error.

dspace import -a -e admin -c capes/218424 -s C:/Users/admins/Desktop/projects/community/migration/bitstreams -z SimpleArchiveFormat.zip -m mapfilesCOM

Comment: Another guess... try passing the full path to the zip file in the -z parameter.

Comment: Not work..

 dspace import -a -e admin -c capes/218424 
-s C:\Users\admins\Desktop\projects\community\migration\bitstre‌​ams 
-z C:\Users\admins\Desktop\projects\community\migration\bitstre‌​ams\SimpleArchiveFormat.zip -m mapfilesCOM

dspace import -a -e admin -c capes/218424 -s C:/Users/admins/Desktop/projects/community/migration/bitstre‌​ams -z C:/Users/admins/Desktop/projects/community/migration/bitstre‌​ams/SimpleArchiveFormat.zip -m mapfilesCOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is this known (and fixed) bug in some versions of DSpace: https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-3585

You should either upgrade to a more recent version or reproduce the fix that is described in the issue and in DSpace's Git.

Good luck !

Comment: It worked in my case I just updated the ItemImport.java file. Our version of dspace is 5.6. Thank you.